# Rails stylesheet_link_tag is linking to the wrong place

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm trying to get my rails app looking even passably nice for the first time, and I'm having a lot of trouble getting stylesheets working.

In my `application.html.erb` layout file, I have the line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'formtastic', 'formtastic_changes', :cache => "base" %>
```

Which, I thought, was supposed to do all of the work. But when I load the page, the stylesheet doesn't load at all. After poking around a bit I found the problem, but don't have the foggiest idea how to fix it!

Instead of loading the stylesheet from  `localhost:3000/stylesheets/application.css`

my browser is trying to load from `localhost:3000/myApp/stylesheets/application.css`

and can't find the sheet there (since it doesn't exist there..)

So, any ideas how I can fix this? And, more generally, why some paths end up looking like `localhost:3000/myApp/page` and some look like `localhost:3000/page`

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you modified the routes ?  Check via 'rake routes' to see what differences may exist

Comment: I don't quite understand? What am I looking for in rake routes?

Comment: Can you provide the link to your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your relative url root variable. Check your app and see if you're setting 
`ActionController::Base.relative_url_root`
or  `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search your app config directory for mention of 'myApp'.  There is something in there that is overriding default route or asset_dir behavior.
2. try removing `:cache => "base"` as an argument.  This concatinates and caches the stylesheets together (in production mode) and might be interfering.

In general, make sure you are always using helper functions to generate links and urls for your views.  (link_to, url_for, form_for, link_to_remote, etc.)  This should make urls consistent across the app.